# Flask not activating debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, flask

I am getting started with flask, I am trying to follow some tutorials, but I have been unable to run Flask app in debug mode.

I tried the simplest code I found:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.debug = True
# I have also tried with a configuration
# app.config.from_object('config')
# file with constant
# DEBUG = True

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Then I run

```
export FLASK_APP=hello_world.py
flask run
```

But I allways get this output

```
 * Serving Flask app "hello_world.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I run `print(app.debug)` I get `False`

This is the output of pip freeze:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

And I have python 3.8.2

Comment: Not sure why those options aren't working. You can set an environment variable though: `export FLASK_DEBUG=1`

Comment: Oh, you have to do both: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45896649/42346

Comment: setting FLASK_DEBUG environment variable works, but I want it to work as it should. Am I the only one who is having this issue? Can you reproduce this error on your machines?

Comment: There are two different things to be done, apparently. Setting `app.debug = True` is one, and setting `FLASK_DEBUG` is the other. That's my understanding of it.

Comment: set environment variable `export FLASK_ENV=development`

Answer (score 14):

I have tried the below steps and it worked for me.

Have added these lines of codes to my **app.py** file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then I ran the program from the **Terminal** using the command line

```
python3 app.py
```

and it worked.

Please find the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: This worked for me as well. I mean, the command. I was running the app via `flask run` and it ignore every setting for me. Any clue what's the difference in these 2 commands?

Comment: @Xonshiz `flask run` runs `app.py` as a module, so `__name__ != "__main_"`. This command runs the file directly so `__name__ == "__main__"`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had forgotten about this comment lol. Thanks for update :D

Answer (score 7):

if you are using windows just type the following in your terminal :
in PowerShell:

```
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
flask run
```

in command prompt :

```
C:\path\to\app>set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

and for mac you probably need to run this :

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

enjoy !!

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. The issue I was having is that the Powershell command was different than the command prompt command. I was trying the command prompt command on powershell

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

When you run,

```
export FLASK_APP=hello_world.py
```

Run this command after the above,

```
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Finally,

```
flask run
```

I hope this would start the debug mode.

Comment: $env:FLASK_DEBUG = 1

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to run Flask App.

- Environment Variable
- Programmatically
   
  **Environment Variable** you need to `exporting` the `FLASK_APP` file using command for window `set FLASK_APP = *(file_name)*`.

```
set FLASK_APP = app.py`
```

And for `mac`

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

You can also control debug mode separately from the environment by exporting `FLASK_DEBUG=1`. (`set` command for `mac` and `export` for `window`)

```
set FLASK_APP = app.py
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

But sometimes debugger does not work on production servers. It is a major security risk to be used on production machines.

**Programmatically** you have to include main section on your Flask app.py main file. It will run your app in debug mode easily but do not use `flask run` command use only `python (file_name)` command.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
python app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I also faced. I was running the application via flask run. and my debug always remains off. Then I try to run it via python app.py and then debug is on.

So, just try to run with "python app.py"

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you're running the right program, sometimes it happens
  that we're making changes in some other program and running something
  else.
- Also ensure that  Setting app.debug = True is altogether a
  different thing from setting FLASK_DEBUG mode to on.

Try this, this works at my end.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, because debug mode is already off, stopping and rerunning it didn't work.
add the line below to app.py and save.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

restart the editor.
then run

```
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

then run your project

```
python3 app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case neither setting the environment variable, nor setting `app.debug = True` helped. What did work was explicitly passing `--debug` [parameter](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/cli/#debug-mode) to the `flask run`:

```bash
flask run --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but with this setting below:

if **name** == "**main**":
app.run(debug=True)

You only need to change the way you start run your code. Instead of using flask run, use python app.py. Assuming the main file is named app.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to `app.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Instead of running `flask run` run:

`python3 app.py`