# Flask is not reacting to the FLASK_ENV variable setting

Tags: python, flask, python-dotenv

I am trying to activate debug mode in Flask.

What I have tried so far:

- set FLASK_ENV=development directly in Windows cmd
- pip installed python-dotenv successfully and set FLASKENV=development in .env file
- ensured that there is no dotenv package globally and within virtual env
- pip force uninstall/reinstall python-dotenv a few times
- with python-dotenv, tried `load_dotenv()` and `os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')` and it shows that the value of FLASK_ENV is `development`

None of the above enabled the debug mode of Flask. FLASK_APP variable is correctly set and read though. Only by running `Flask --debug run` activates the debug mode.

Why is the FLASK_ENV variable not recognized by Flask?

Comment: Looks like it was removed: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0

Comment: Use `FLASK_DEBUG` instead: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#DEBUG

Comment: Indeed. `FLASK_DEBUG` fixed it. You might like to make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [ivvija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10513287/ivvija): In [Flask version 2.3.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0), the `FLASK_ENV` environment variable (including the `ENV` config key and `app.env` property) has been removed.

You should instead set `FLASK_DEBUG=1`, or [set `debug=True` in your `app.run()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65059851/8602304) method or use the [`--debug` option when running the `flask run` command](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#debug-mode) to enable debug mode - any of these will work.

Comment: This is hard to catch as most tutorials out there are outdated.